# How would one identify ionic thrust vs chemical thrust in an orbit transfer?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, engines, ion-thruster, low-energy-transfer

My nomenclature might be a bit off, I’m no expert but I’ve been reading to solve the question all the same. Say we detect an orbit transfer based off ephemeris records. We can get the 6 classic orbit elements for both. Is there something about ionic thrusters vs chemical that is so obvious we can figure out what kind of thruster was used based on “some mystery to me” computation? Because of the complexity of the question “Go read ‘xyz’” is also a very acceptable answer. If given a book please also give chapter number(s). I’m sure the information is out there, I currently just don’t have it.

Comment: There is an obvious difference, it is the thrust. The ionic thrust is tiny compared to the chemical thrust. Chemical thrust could be used for only some seconds to a few minutes. Ionic thrust is used for many hours and even many days.

Comment: I worded the question carefully to try and avoid this confusion. The question is assuming you know nothing about the thrust, only the two orbits and maybe the delta t of the two ephemerides. Like backpropagation of Vallado in chapter 6.7. It's a real world example, not a theoretical one. Classifying someone else's maneuver not your own where you know/control nothing about it.

Comment: If you know the time interval needed for the transfer between the two orbits as well as data of the orbits ( the 6 classic orbit elements ), you can calculate the energy difference between the orbits. If we assume constant ionic thrust for the transfer time, we can calculate the ionic power as the quotient of energy and time. If this power is within the range of ionic thrusters, the transfer was possible using an ionic thruster. If the power is some orders of magnitude above the  the range of ionic thrusters, a chemical thruster must have been used.

Answer (score 2):

This is possibly a bit of a stretch, so do correct me if I am wrong.

Let's assume you have access to the TLE data of the satellite. You could compare the ballistic coefficients of the object before and after the maneuver, giving you an estimate of the change in mass. Further, you can calculate the delta-v of the maneuver, and with some more calculation estimate the Isp of the engine. A higher Isp indicated electric propulsion, lower Isp indicates chemical propulsion.

Additionally, as others have suggested, you may calculate the time and further the power requirement.

Comment: Can you explain how to derive Isp from two TLEs? A worked out example would be nice.

Comment: Perhaps you could use the vis-viva equation and plug in values and see change in t over time?